# Why the rectangle drawn outside the circle with opencv is not displaying?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want a rectangular bounding box outside the circle.

[image]

I have a depth image and I have the x,y, and r.From that, I draw the circle and I want to create a rectangle bounding box outside the circle. But every time it's showing me the circle only.

Below is my code:

```
images = glob.glob(--image path--)
gt_boxes = open(--ground truth location--, 'r+')
data = list(zip(images, gt_boxes))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
for n in range(0,len(data)):

   img = cv2.imread(df1.iloc[n][0],0)

   id1 = df1[1][n]
   id_1, x, y, r = [int(x) for x in id1.split()]

   print(df1.iloc[n][0],id_1)
   img1 = cv2.circle(img,(x,y), r, (0,255,255), 1)
   #print(df1.iloc[n][0],id_1)
   x1 = x-r
   y1 = y+r
   w1 = 2*r
   h1 = 2*r
   print(x1,y1,w1,h1)
   rect = cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y1),(x1+w1,y1+h1),(0,255,255),3)
   cv2.imshow("rectangle",rect)
   cv2.waitKey(50)
   key = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
   if key == ord("q"):
     break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Post the current output image and the expected output image.

Comment: You may want to manipulate always the same image object, not different image objects. https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html

Comment: try replacing `img1` with `img` when assigning `rect` variable

Comment: @JeruLuke I tried with replacing img 1 with img. Even if the output is only the circle.

Comment: @Mika72 I tried replacing img1 of the rectangle with img but every time the circle is only showing

Comment: try printing `cv2.imshow("rectangle",img)` for the same code. Replace `rect` with `img`.

Comment: there are bugs in your code,  `y1 = y+r`probably has to be ` y1 = y-r` instead. You did print x1, y1, w1, h1, did you check those values? Did you try to draw them hard-coded for a single image? Did you try to draw different rectangles hard-coded to test whether you have any problems in your data/parameter format?

Comment: btw, in C++ no image is returned but the structure is drawn inside the input image. Maybe that's the same for the python verison. Did you try to display `img`?

Comment: Also, for some reason you're trying to draw in colour (`(0,255,255)`) into a grayscale image.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:
`rect = cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y1),(x1+w1,y1+h1),(0,255,255),3)`

Run:
`cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y1),(x1+w1,y1+h1),(0,255,255),3)`

and then run `imshow()` on img instead.

Another reason could be that the grey channel image is only picking up the `B` component of your `(0,255,255)` color object, so the rectangle is drawn, but not visible